# task config for arm-none-eabi-gcc

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm looking for help to correctly configure *task.json* file to build C/C++ project with `arm-none-eabi-gcc` compiler.

I can compile C-project as `arm-none-eabi-gcc -specs=nosys.specs hello_c.c -o hello_c.out` from command-line.

but configuration using *task.json* under `vscode`

```json
"version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "arm-none-eabi-gcc build active file",
            "command": "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain\\9 2020-q2-update\\bin\\arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-specs=nosys.specs",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.bin"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain\\9 2020-q2-update\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: c:\\Program Files (x86)\\GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain\\9 2020-q2-update\\bin\\arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

it outputs

```
> Executing task: arm-none-eabi-gcc build active file <

Starting build...
Build finished with error:
c:/program files (x86)/gnu arm embedded toolchain/9 2020-q2-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: c:/program files (x86)/gnu arm embedded toolchain/9 2020-q2-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libg.a(lib_a-exit.o): in function `exit':
exit.c:(.text.exit+0x2c): undefined reference to `_exit'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu arm embedded toolchain/9 2020-q2-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: c:/program files (x86)/gnu arm embedded toolchain/9 2020-q2-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libg.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): in function `_sbrk_r':
sbrkr.c:(.text._sbrk_r+0x18): undefined reference to `_sbrk'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu arm embedded toolchain/9 2020-q2-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: c:/program files (x86)/gnu arm embedded toolchain/9 2020-q2-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libg.a(lib_a-writer.o): in function `_write_r':
writer.c:(.text._write_r+0x28): undefined reference to `_write'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu arm embedded toolchain/9 2020-q2-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: c:/program files (x86)/gnu arm embedded toolchain/9 2020-q2-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libg.a(lib_a-closer.o): in function `_close_r':
closer.c:(.text._close_r+0x18): undefined reference to `_close'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu arm embedded toolchain/9 2020-q2-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: c:/program files (x86)/gnu arm embedded toolchain/9 2020-q2-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libg.a(lib_a-lseekr.o): in function `_lseek_r':
lseekr.c:(.text._lseek_r+0x28): undefined reference to `_lseek'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu arm embedded toolchain/9 2020-q2-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: c:/program files (x86)/gnu arm embedded toolchain/9 2020-q2-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libg.a(lib_a-readr.o): in function `_read_r':
readr.c:(.text._read_r+0x28): undefined reference to `_read'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu arm embedded toolchain/9 2020-q2-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: c:/program files (x86)/gnu arm embedded toolchain/9 2020-q2-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libg.a(lib_a-fstatr.o): in function `_fstat_r':
fstatr.c:(.text._fstat_r+0x20): undefined reference to `_fstat'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu arm embedded toolchain/9 2020-q2-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: c:/program files (x86)/gnu arm embedded toolchain/9 2020-q2-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libg.a(lib_a-isattyr.o): in function `_isatty_r':
isattyr.c:(.text._isatty_r+0x18): undefined reference to `_isatty'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).
```

Comment: I have the same problem with an ordinary c++ file. I've replaced the compiler with the script that outputs its command line arguments. It looks like "args" from the task configuration are totally ignored. :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've changed the "type" to "shell" and it worked. Just as in the example task here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac. It looks like "cppbuild" type is currently broken, or we don't really know how to use it properly.

Comment: So I did replace for `"type": "shell"` but the error is till there ...

Comment: Now it works: I've changed for `"type": "shell"`and `"--specs=nosys.specs",` to have a double hyphen :) Thanks.